# wordpress json_decode is not working, I am trying to get value form wp_option table

Tags: json, wordpress, wordpress-theming

When I am trying to decode JSON with this code the output is

```
ArrayArray ( [0] => )
```

I do not know why WordPress doesn't support this

```
 <?php
    global $wpdb;
    $mylink = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_id=62167", ARRAY_N );
    $raw = stripslashes_deep($mylink);
            $data = array();
            foreach ($raw as $json) {
                        echo $json;

                $item = @json_decode($json, true);

                $data[] = $item;

                            print_r($data);

            }
    ?>
```

Comment: nothing to do with wp at all, its all php. check your raw variable, id say you have @ there to hide the error it would be generating

Comment: Please can you suggest me , what should i do for that, I just want to fetch wp_options column option_value json data and want  to decode this as a json _decode , please help me

Comment: Why are you suppressing errors? `@json_decode($json, true);` Use just `json_decode` and see what happens. Also try printing out your query, as well as your `$item`, to see what they contain...

Comment: Hello Dingo_d, IF i passing value in json_decode($json,true) it's return nothing ,  if i print this line  $raw = stripslashes_deep($mylink); i ma getting json value , but when i trying to decode this , it's not return any thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello you need to unserealize the data first when your query get data from database,
That is serealized data and when we get it from db we need to unserealize it.

```
 global $wpdb;
    $mylink = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_id=1223",ARRAY_A);

   $raw = stripslashes_deep($mylink);
  $data = $raw[0]['option_value'];
  $datas = unserialize($data);
  foreach ($datas as $key => $value) {
    print_r($value);
  }
```

Comment: HI piyush, when I am using this code , getting error/*
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\paytmbigbo\wp-content\themes\StepAhead\serviceprovider.php on line 57*/

Comment: Hi piyush  thanks for  understanding  my script, you save my life , it's awesome, it's beautiful experience ,

Comment: HI, This is  awesome experience , script is running, you save my life, Thanks