# I am trying to print value of key from json

Tags: php, mysql, json, wordpress

I am fetching data from database and getting json result .Result is like this.

```
[{\"product\":\"AAAAAA\"},{\"product\":\"WWWWW\"}] .
```

I am trying to remove slace with preg_replace function.But its did not working.

```
preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', $string);
```

My sql query is.

```
$user1 = $wpdb->get_results("select product,checked_by,date(submit_date) from diary_user_form_storage where DATE(submit_date) = CURDATE() ;");
foreach ($user1 as $key => $value) {
    json_decode($value->product);


     echo $result=$value->product;
}
```

And output result is

```
[{\"product\":\"AAAAAA\"},{\"product\":\"WWWWW\"}][{\"product\":\"FFFF\"},{\"product\":\"ASSS\"}]
```

I want decode this json and try to get get key value.Any help

Comment: use var data = JSON.parse(response) in your javascript code.

Comment: [`json_decode($value)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)  should work before you echo anything

Comment: pdshah3690@I have not javascript code . can you implement this I am very new

Comment: apokryfos@@please see the updated question  
json_decode($value) not working

Comment: try sripslashesh and then json_decode

Comment: have a look at https://3v4l.org/bv5f6

Comment: Something very odd with your result. Do you actually have JSON stored in the database or is there some code you're not showing us here?

Comment: apokryfos@its' already stored  in databse . with same code

Comment: @sanjaykumar you mean this:  [{\"product\":\"AAAAAA\"},{\"product\":\"WWWWW\"}] ?

Comment: Hassan Ali Salem@ yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[json_decode php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

first you dont need to remove backslashes..

you should provide json_decode with bool $assoc = true;

so it will return an associative array

#### example:

```
$json = "[{\"product\":\"AAAAAA\"},{\"product\":\"WWWWW\"}]";
$array = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($array);
```

[image]

```
$user1 = $wpdb->get_results(
    "select product,checked_by,date(submit_date) from diary_user_form_storage where DATE(submit_date) = CURDATE() ;
");

$jsonString = "";
foreach ($user1 as $key => $value) {
    $productString = stripslashes($value->product);
    $product = json_decode($productString, true);
    var_dump($product): // array of key and value
    echo $result=$value->product; 
}
```

Comment: Hassan Ali Salem@@ same output [{\"product\":\"HDHD\"},{\"product\":\"GSSHS\"}]

Comment: @sanjaykumar,  yes sure it will be the same output
you are echoing the $value->product, and that is its value,
in my solution your actual needed value is in $product, you can var_dump it

Comment: please take a look to the picture in my answer,
it is decoded normally

Comment: @sanjaykumar, you mean the $product variable?

Comment: where do you use it?
outside the foreach or inside it??

Comment: Hassan Ali Salem@@inside of foreach

Comment: @sanjaykumar, if $value->product contains this: [{\"product\":\"AAAAAA\"},{\"product\":\"WWWWW\"}], so the json_decode should work normally,
I did it on my local environment (look at the pic), but if your result is something else please paste it here

Comment: Hassan Ali Salem@you right but why I am post wrong value.please see the  refrence . its happen many time ago .may be  we get some help ,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35687733/wordpress-json-decode-is-not-working-i-am-trying-to-get-value-form-wp-option-ta

Comment: Hassan Ali Salem@you there

Comment: @sanjaykumar, yes sure. Iam trying to do what you did on my local env :D

Comment: @sanjaykumar, did you try to stripslashes ?
stripcslashes ($string) before decoding it

Comment: Hassan Ali Salem@I did not try this

Comment: @sanjaykumar, I updated the answer, take a look please

Comment: Hassan Ali Salem@ok I am checking this

Comment: Hassan Ali Salem@you there its working.but can you let me know how can i print  only array key value.

Comment: yes sure @sanjaykumar, you can do array_keys($array), or if you want it as string you can do: implode(array_keys($array), ', ')

Comment: Hassan Ali Salem@please I  ma in problem can you implement this for me .this is a related question

Comment: Hassan Ali Salem@please see this question link @https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46684245/how-can-print-array-value-of-key

Comment: Hassan Ali Salem@you there bro .I need your help

Comment: Hi @sanjaykumar, sure, what is the problem?

Comment: Hassan Ali Salem@this same code I am trying for other place .I am generating pdf for database value. but same code there does not work.please see this link  here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46804853/fetch-json-data-type-from-database?noredirect=1#comment80559391_46804853

Comment: Hassan Ali Salem@totla death condition I do not why json_decode  does not work to another place

Answer (score 0):

You can use json_decode().

```
$data = [{\"product\":\"AAAAAA\"},{\"product\":\"WWWWW\"}];
print_r(json_decode($data, true));
```

and your output will be like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product] => AAAAAA
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product] => WWWWW
        )

)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code,

$user1 = $wpdb->get_results("select product,checked_by,date(submit_date) from diary_user_form_storage where DATE(submit_date) = CURDATE() ;");
foreach ($user1 as $key => $value) {

```
json_decode($value->product);
// I think you got output for $value->product like this  "[{\"product\":\"AAAAAA\"},{\"product\":\"WWWWW\"}]", if yes, then follow below code 

$pro = json_decode("[{\"product\":\"AAAAAA\"},{\"product\":\"WWWWW\"}]");


 foreach ($pro as $p) {
  echo $p->product;
 }
```

}

Output is:
AAAAAAWWWWW