# How can print array value of key

Tags: php, mysql

I am unable to print value of array key returned by this query:

```
    $user1 = $wpdb->get_results(
        "select product,checked_by,date(submit_date) from diary_user_form_storage where DATE(submit_date) = CURDATE() ;
    ");

    $jsonString = "";
    foreach ($user1 as $key => $value) {
    $productString = stripslashes($value->product);
    $checked = stripslashes($value->checked_by);
    $suppliers = stripslashes($value->suppliers);
    $van_temperature = stripslashes($value->van_temperature);
    $comments = stripslashes($value->comments);
    $product = json_decode($productString, true);
    $checked_by = json_decode($checked , true);
    $suppliers = json_decode($suppliers , true);
    $van_temperature = json_decode($van_temperature, true);
    $comments = json_decode($comments, true);
//This code is running for single variable $product But I have to print all //multiple variable here . How can I print multiple variable here 

    foreach ($product as $v){
       echo  $v['product']; 
    }
}
?>
```

This is the result that's printed

```
[1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["product"]=>
    string(5) "GSSHS"
  }
}
```

If i did print_r for my SQL query print_r($user1) ,Then output is array list you can see.

```
 [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [store_id] => 2
            [user_id] => 7
            [unit_data] => [{\"unit_data\":\"10\"}]
            [suppliers] => 
            [product] => [{\"product\":\"AA\"}]
            [checked_by] => [{\"checked_by\":\"Rakesh Kushwaha\"}]
            [temperature_in] => [{\"temperature_in\":\"QWW\"}]
            [temperature_out] => 
            [time_in] => [{\"time_in\":\"44:44\"}]
            [time_out] => 
            [van_temperature] => 
            [center_temperature] => 
            [cooling_temperature] => 
            [end_cooling_temperature] => 
            [comments] => 
            [submit_date] => 2017-10-18 22:12:39
            [time_holded] => 
            [temperature] => 
            [time_reheated] => 
            [extra_timing] => 
            [image_url] => 
            [category_name] => opening
            [category] => [{\"category\":\"Frozen\"}]
        )
```

I only need the value of this key of array: `["product"]=>"GSSHS"`

Comment: please can you print all the results so you can put var_dump on $product beffore the foreach thing, var_dump($product)

Comment: Hello, can you please print all the result: $user1 content?

Comment: Hassan Ali Salem @yes I can print

Comment: Hello Sanjay, I updated the answer, try it and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user ARRAY_A

```
$user1 = $wpdb->get_results(
    "select product,checked_by,date(submit_date) from diary_user_form_storage where DATE(submit_date) = CURDATE() ;
",ARRAY_A);
```

Comment: somin@invalid forech argument

Comment: using ARRAY_A it will return array result of query so you need to make change in your foreach because you are using data as object not it will show as array

Comment: Somin@can  use explode and print this value.

Comment: can i have link where you are trying so i can check?

Answer (score 0):

first you cannot use the arrow notation with array

because json_decode($jsonString, true) will return an array

you can use it without the true flag or just access it as array

so you cannot use it like this:

```
foreach ($product as $v){
   echo $v->product; 
}
```

try to use it like:

```
foreach ($product as $v){
   echo $v['product']; 
}
```

according to your update

everything you are doing is right.But the problem is in your indexes.
now try to do this:

```
foreach($product as $p) {
    if(!empty($p[0]['product'])) {
        echo $p[0]['product'];
    }
}
```

or you can replace the if with shorter one:

```
echo !empty($p[0]['product'])? $p[0]['product']: null;
```

Comment: Hassan Ali Salem@I am trying to print this but it's print numeric value 4

Comment: Hi @sanjaykumar, try to do it like this: $v[0]['product'], and please show me the content of the product variable

Comment: Hassan Ali Salem@its workign good . but  if i have print multiple column then how can i  do this .so please can you please let me  know  I print multiple data  like $v['product']; $v['username']; etc

Comment: Hassan Ali Salem@please see my updated question bro I need your help .please , you there , only you can do this

Comment: Hello @sanjaykumar, I will do it for you, but I need some time, because Iam at work now :D, I will do it in my break

Comment: Hassan Ali Salem @please see my updated question ,after print_r ,output is array list